# simplest way to parse Resellerclub HTTP API Response

Tags: c#, parsing, dns, deserialization

Below is the http request for the check domain availability to the HTTP API of ResellerClub:

```
https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=166694&auth-password=span2012&domain-name=prasadvemala&domain-name=prasadvemala2&tlds=com&tlds=com
```

Below is the response from it:

```
{"prasadvemala.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"},"prasadvemala2.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}
```

What is the simplest way to parse this response in C#?

Comment: You want to parse JSON to C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) is best for quick and dirty Json parsing:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(responseString);
var val = jObj["prasadvemala.com"]["status"].Value<string>();
```

It's avaliable as a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) too.

EDIT

If you want to enumerate the entire response:

```
var everythingDictionary = jObj
    .Properties()
    .Select(p => new{
        key=p.Name,
        value=new{
            status=p.Value["status"].Value<string>(),
            classkey=p.Value["classkey"].Value<string>()}})
    .ToDictionary(x => x.key,x => x.value);

foreach(var k in everythingDictionary.Keys)
{
    var name = k;
    var status = everythingDictionary[k].status;
    var classkey = everythingDictionary[k].classkey;
}
```

Comment: spender, This works fine. One more question, how do we parse it in a foreach loop and get the domain names within the loop and get the status value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the JSON parser in [this article](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/14605/14863/How-do-I-write-my-own-parser-for-JSON.html) quite good for scenarios where the JSON structure may have dynamically named properties. It returns simple nested Hashtables of all properties and sub objects.